# How to Hide/disable Edit/View button from sharepoint Ribbon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to hide/disable  Edit/View button from sharepoint list ribbon, but not able to.

Please let me know if someone can help me. I can only use JavaScript.

Also, Please note that I want to hide only two buttons(Edit/View) not the whole ribbon.

Comment: Please refer,
 http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2012/08/sharepoint-ribbon-css-tips-tricks/

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to Hide the Ribbon as shown below.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideRbn()
{
var elmID = document.getElementById("RIBBONID");
elmID.style.display = "none";
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideRbn");
</script>
```